# Does the shard (Elasticsearch) have its own JVM settings

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going through ES documentation and saw this following

```
Each shard is in itself a fully-functional and independent "index" that can be hosted on any node in the cluster.
```

Does "fully functional" means it is a "seperate" lucene instance or thread that can  have its own hardware and software resources associated with it?

If it is, is it possible to configure different shards to use different configurations of RAM

Answer (score 1):

No and kind of yes at the same time.

1. Lucene only "sees" that one shard and thinks that's all there is; the rest is being taken care of by Elasticsearch. But you are not interacting with Lucene directly and you are also not configuring it explicitly.
2. Your quote is correct, but could be misleading: Assume you have 5 Elasticsearch nodes on different hardware nodes and a single index with 5 shards (to keep it simple let's say 0 replicas). While it's not guaranteed there is a chance that every Elasticsearch / hardware node will have a single shard. And then every node could have a different hardware and Elasticsearch configuration. So while this is possible it's not the most common scenario.
3. What you would normally do is to configure different node types; for example hot (today's data with lots of writes and reads) - warm (the last week without writes but frequent reads) - cold (the last year without writes and infrequent reads) might be an option for a logging usecase. And then you could filter each index on which node type it should be stored. The concept is generally called [Shard Allocation Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html).

Comment: awesome explanation. thanks @xeraa. waiting for some more comments